# How do you make Cube not instantly rotate upon Keypress in opposite direction?

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rotate

I have this movement script on a `Rigidbody` cube with X,Y,Z Rotation Constraints.

It is working well to move and to rotate in the direction of the movement.

However, if for example you Keypress W and then Keypress S, the rotation is instant! There is no smooth rotating effect. How might you make rotation on such condition be a smooth directional rotation (making cube turn around at a smooth angle), rather than an instant transform flip?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveCube : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody r;

    public float horizontalInput;
    public float verticalInput;
    public Vector3 movDirection;
    public float speed = 10f;
    public float heyo;
    private Vector3 prevPosition;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Awake()
    {
        r = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        prevPosition = transform.position;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        movDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput).normalized;
    }
    public void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // Calculate position change between frames
        Vector3 deltaPosition = transform.position - prevPosition;
        deltaPosition.y = 0f;

        if (deltaPosition != Vector3.zero)
        {
            // Same effect as rotating with quaternions, but simpler to read
            transform.forward = deltaPosition;
        }
        // Recording current position as previous position for next frame
        prevPosition = transform.position;



        r.AddForce(movDirection * (speed + 18f), ForceMode.Force);
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of assigning the rotation as you are, try incrementing it with https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.RotateTowards.html and use fixed delta time times degrees per second as max step. This will gradually rotate the transform instead of instantly snapping it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't actually use Unity, but I do some 2D game programming and I use C#, so I'll chip in an idea hopefully it might help.

From what I know a technique to create a smoothing-effect for movement is to linear-interpolate ("LERP") the movement of the target object against the profile of some function. It sounds a little complex but at a high level it's a good approach.

Take for example a straight horizontal line on a graph. If we were to linearly interpolate this function's profile, we'd end up with 'x'-values that change as we go along it, but the 'y'-values would stay the same.
So you'd end up with a rigid, un-smooth movement to your object.

But if you alias the movement over time between two ends of say, a diagonal line going up that curves to a straight horizontal line, then your 'y'-values would be "smoothed-out" somewhat. I don't have a code example but I hope this might help a bit.

Research: Advanced Game Development with Programmable Graphics Hardware
By Alan Watt, Fabio Policarpo (p.201) - https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Advanced_Game_Development_with_Programma/EUFZDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0

(In the GIF, I basically smoothed out the arrows movement with an acceleration-style functionality that increases linearly up to a threshold, but I didn't apply it to the slow-down due to time. However a naïve "LERP" like this might be what you could use)

[image]